# Avoid rescaling colorbar (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, colorbar

this [function](http://pastebin.com/XvhN6EkD) plots a 3-variables-function with colors... 
Please try it... You'll see that the colorbar is too compressed. But if you comment the line that says "plot_plane..." the colorbar appears properly...

Here's the code of the [plot_plane function](http://pastebin.com/QZzRn0NE)

Here are pictures showing what happens:

With plot_plane...

[image]

Without plot_plane...

Any idea on how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Try `caxis` maybe?

Comment: Kinda worked but don't know how to get it to get the original scale again... I'm just doing the images with the wrong scale and then I'll paste the correct one above with an image editor...